# Does having an isomorphism between two could-be groups imply that they are groups?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism

I know that the title is a bit of a word salad, but I couldn't find a better way to ask it concisely. Here is the question:

Let's say I have an operation $*$ such that for any $a,b \in \mathbb R$,

$$x * y =  \sqrt[3]{(x^3 + y^3)}.$$

I also have an application $f: x \mapsto x^3$ that is an isomorphism of $(\mathbb R, *) \to (\mathbb R, +)$. How can I deduce that $(\mathbb R, *)$ is a commutative group from the fact that f is an isomorphism from $(\mathbb R, *) \to (\mathbb R, +)$?

I'm not really sure how to even go about this. I also assumed that the the source and destination of isomorphisms *were* groups by definitions, but I guess that's wrong? A point towards the right direction would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: This is not clear.  What does "isomorphism" mean in this context?

Comment: I agree with @lulu, you can have different types of isomorphisms depending on the algebraic structure you are working with ie. sets, groups, rings... Your question made me think of a property that might help you: Let (G,*) be an abelian group and (G,$\cdot$) denotes just an inner operation in G. If you have a map $f:G\rightarrow G$ that is a bijection and preserves the structure, then (G,$\cdot$) is also an abelian group.

Comment: The word "homomorphism" or "isomorphism" makes only sense when we already have a group. Homomorphisms preserve a structure. If there is not structure, there is nothing to preserve, and there are no homomorphisms.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. As the answer underneath states, is it not possible to have a isomorphism of magmas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the main point of confusion is that "isomorphism" here is being used in a broader context than you are used to. In this context we have, on the face of it, a [**magma**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magma_(algebra)): this is a fancy name for a set together with a binary operation. Note that *every group is a magma*, but not conversely: the set $\{0,1\}$ equipped with the binary operation $*$ which always outputs "$1$" is a magma but not a group *(there is no identity element, since $x*0=1\not=0$ regardless of what $x$ is)*.

We now define an isomorphism of magmas. If $\mathcal{A}_1=(A_1, *_1)$ and  $\mathcal{A}_2=(A_2, *_2)$ are magmas, then a magma isomorphism from $\mathcal{A}_1$ to $\mathcal{A}_2$ is a function $i: A_1\rightarrow A_2$ such that:

- $i$ is a bijection.
- For all $a, b\in A_1$, we have $i(a*_1b)=i(a)*_2i(b)$.

Note that this looks exactly like the definition of an isomorphism for groups! In general, **every kind of mathematical structure has an associated notion of "isomorphism."** *(This theme is taken up in more detail in [abstract algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_algebra), and then developed even further in [category theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_theory).)*

---

Now let's look at the actual question. The point is that if we have two things (in this case, magmas) which are isomorphic, then they are "algebraically identical" - any algebraic property which one has, the other also has. In particular, if one is a group so is the other.

Here's a concrete example:

> Suppose $(A_1, *_1)\cong (A_2, *_2)$ are isomorphic magmas and $(A_1, *_1)$ has an identity element. Then $(A_2, *_2)$ has an identity element.

*Proof*. Let $e$ be the identity element of $(A, *_1)$ and $i$ be some isomorphism from $(A_1, *_1)$ to $(A_2, *_2)$. I claim $i(e)$ is the identity element of $(A_2, *_2)$.

To see this, pick $b\in A_2$; we want to show $i(e)*_2b=b*_2i(e)=b$. Since $i$ is a bijection, $b$ "comes from" some element of $A_1$; let $a=i^{-1}(b)$. We now argue as follows:

- Since $e$ is the identity in $(A_1, *_1)$, we have $e*_1a=a$. Since $i$ is an isomorphism, we have $$i(a)=i(e*_1a)=i(e)*_2i(a).$$ But $i(a)=b$, so this tells us that $$b=i(e)*_2b.$$
- Similarly, since $e$ is the identity in $(A_1, *_1)$, we have $a*_1e=a$. Since $i$ is an isomorphism, we have $$i(a)=i(a*_1e)=i(a)*_2i(e).$$ But $i(a)=b$, so this tells us that $$b=b*_2i(e).$$

Now you want to show:

> If $\mathcal{A},\mathcal{B}$ are isomorphic magmas and $\mathcal{A}$ is a group, then so is $\mathcal{B}$.

By the above argument, we've shown that the existence of identities "ports over" from $\mathcal{A}$ to $\mathcal{B}$. We now just need to check the other group axioms!

- Show that the associativity of $\mathcal{A}$ implies that $\mathcal{B}$ is associative.
- Show that the existence of inverses in $\mathcal{A}$ implies the existence of inverses in $\mathcal{B}$.

Once you've done this, you'll be finished.

Comment: Wow, just wow. This is the best answer I could have hoped for, and more.  Thank you very much. At my first-year level, is it safe to take this as a given? Is there a name for this property of isomorphisms that I can call on in such a situation? My best guess here is that they wanted me to mention that (R, +) is a group - that's a given - and since f is isometric between the magma (awesome word btw), then (R, *) is a group.

Comment: Maybe I'm understimating what's expected of me though? Honestly, I'd love to be able to complete these kinds of proofs, but I don't feel as though I have the intuition nor the skill to be able to do one on my own. I will certainly try, though. Thank you very much once again, I really appreciate the help.